# UIBezierPath persistence with core data

Tags: ios, core-data, uibezierpath

I am working on an application where the user is able to draw on the screen with their finger. I am using UIBezierPath for this. I need to persist this data which is an NSArray containing multiple BezierPath objects. What is the best way to go about this? Store in coredata, store in a file using NSData? Much obliged.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you expecting to have to store multiple objects? Will you need to be able to fetch them based on some filter or ordering? I recommend using Core Data to save yourself a decent amount of work in packing/unpacking the data. There isn't really a reason to store it in a file.

**edit:**

As the other answer said, you just archive it to NSData. The [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) class adheres to the NSCoding protocol so you can do something like this to archive it:

```
NSData *bezierData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:bezierPath];
```

You can persist that NSData object in Core Data.

To decode the archive, assuming we have a `bezierData` NSData object, you can do something like:

```
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:bezierData];
```

Comment: How would you persist a UIBesierPath in coredata?

Answer (score 1):

Archive the UIBezierPath to NSData, and store it as an attribute of type NSData in CoreData.  You can have an easier API if you make it a transformable attribute.

It's pretty easy to do, especially for classes that already support archiving.

See this document for more information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html